# Validation text from a textbox still displays text after returning false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have a textbox I would like to only enter numeric values. Right now I have this function

```
    function validate(evt) {
        var theEvent = evt || window.event;
        var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var regex = /[0-9]|\./;
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

and this is my aspx textcontrol

```
   <asp:Panel ID="PanelAddPhoneNumber" runat="server" Style="display: none; min-width: 500px; min-height: 500px;" Title="Add Phone Numbers">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelAddPhoneNums" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPhoneNum" type="text" AutoPostBack="true"  />
                      </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </ContentTemplate>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

my functions is called and everything seems to "work", but say I press "G", it will hit the if inside my function and return false and also hit the    theEvent.PreventDefualt();

but my textbox still displays the "G"?! This is not right.

EDIT: I added in my full aspx side panel. I also tried

$(document).ready(function () {
            $('<%= txtPhoneNum.ClientID %>').keydown(function (event) {

but nothing seemed to work.
Perhaps the update panel is interfering some way? And I apologize, if the situation was how it was stated in the OP, I am sure your solution would have resolved it, both versions So Ill upvote them.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [jQuery Numeric plugin](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/). It's so easy :)

**EDITED:**

If you want validate it without any lib see example below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtPhoneNum").keydown(function (event) {
                // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
                if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 ||
                    // Allow: Ctrl+A
                    (event.keyCode == 65 && event.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    // Allow: home, end, left, right
                    (event.keyCode >= 35 && event.keyCode <= 39)) {
                    // let it happen, don't do anything
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                    if (event.shiftKey || (parseInt(event.target.value) == 1 && event.keyCode > 48) || (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

and FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/jQRR7/47/

I hope this script solves your problem

Comment: Yes, but I am developing software for clients, so unfortunately, I am not too aware of which copyright restrictions plugins fall under even though it might be free. I just don't want to leave anything to chance  by using something pre made like that. But I appreciate the reply.

Comment: It was, but it still didn't seem to resolve my issue. My breakpoint shows that I hit the event.PreventDefault() but it still lets the character get through